# Is there a way to save questions for later reading?

Tags: support

While I am trying to search from my questions, I come across many questions that interest me. I open them and often, I have to close my browser without reading many questions. I know I can use the "Open where left" option in my browser but that bugs me sometimes because of the large number of links that remain open in my browser.

Does SE have an option for saving questions for future reading?
And if not can we have such an option?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet using Stack Exchange UI is [favoriting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585) questions. To do so, just click the star below the *beautifully designed* arrow signs of the questions. You can access the questions you favorited in your profile tab; [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites).

However, I find this feature really annoying, because I have 224 favorites. I suggest you do something else, like exporting the questions as a PDF. For that cause, see [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite?s=1|1.0213). It's really beautiful and awesome and is *teh beste ting*.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark questions as favourites by clicking the grey star below the voting arrows. Questions marked as favourites can then be found on your userpage in the favourites-tab. You just need to remember to check there ;)

Comment: Darn it, I never really wanted to post a comment-ish answer D=